# Jquery-cкрипт для замены разорванных html-тегов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На странице есть несколько форм, куда вставляется размеченный html-тегами текст, но предварительно прошедший через google или яндекс переводчик. Переводчики разрывают некоторые теги и вместо исходного `<span>fish text</span>` они могут выдать `< span> рыбный текст< / span>`.

Конечно, такая верстка неадекватно отображается во фронтенде. Есть код, который меняет исходный текст на указанный `$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/исходник/g, 'замена'))`. Как его расширить, чтобы учитывались все возможные варианты разрывов тегов и они заменялись на свои правильные аналоги? Чтобы можно было или в скрипте перебрать все варианты, дополнять его новыми, или может с помощью регулярных выражений как-то можно все проще сделать?

Comment: Это определённо плохая идея, потому что переводчик может перевести html-теги и всё сломать

Answer (score 1):

Если проблема только в пробелах, которыми разбиваются теги (как Вы указали в примере), то это легко решить, с помощью несложного регулярного выражения.

Попробуйте запустить код и поменять текст в первом поле:

```js
function fInput(oElem) {
  oElem.nextElementSibling.value = oElem.value.replace(/<\s*(\/)?\s*(.*?\S)\s*>/gi, '<$1$2>');
}
```

```css
textarea { display: block; height: 6em; width: 99%; }
```

```html
<textarea oninput="fInput(this);"><span>fish text</span> они могут выдать 
<    span    > рыбный текст< /     span> могут выдать 
< div    > рыбный текст< /  div > могут выдать 
<   p class="foo"> рыбный текст< / p>
< blockquote class="foo_60-90"> рыбный текст< /   blockquote></textarea><textarea></textarea>
```